# How to get DropDownList Selected Value in the Loop in razor View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I already used this code to display the selected value in the dropdown.But now I have a few dropdown in the list I want to display their selected value in the editing form.Please see the code and guide me.but this code does not work for the list, please see the image.Thank you

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.ToList()[i].TaminKoonandeName</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="hf_selected_val" value="@Model.ToList()[i].NoaeFactor" />

            <select class="mt-1 form-control" name="[@i].NoaeFactor" style="font-size: 12px; width: 130px" required autocomplete="off">   
                <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                <option value="1">خرید</option>
                <option value="2">برگشت از خرید</option>   
            </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
}      

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("select[name='NoaeFactor']").each(function () {
            var selectedVal = $(this).prev("input[type='hidden']").val();
            if (selectedVal != "") {
                $(this).val(selectedVal);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: You CSS selector is `"select[name='NoaeFactor']"` but your select elements do not have name attribute that equal to 'NoaeFactor' (`name="[@i].NoaeFactor"`).

Comment: I gave the same name to both, but it didn't open because the dropdown is in the same loop

Comment: Add a specific class to all select elements in loop e.g. `<select class="mt-1 form-control noae-factor-select">` and in javascript do `$(".noae-factor-select").each(...)`.

Comment: Please try this and write me the answer. Thank you

Comment: If I had the source code of your project I would try it. But that is not my job to do, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below:

```
@{
    var sel1 = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "A1", Value = "A1" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "A2", Value = "A2" } };
    var sel2 = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "B1", Value = "B1" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "B2", Value = "B2" } };
    var sel3 = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "C1", Value = "C1" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "C2", Value = "C2" } };
}
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="input1" />
        
            <select asp-items="sel1"onchange="Somefunc()"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="input2" />
        
            <select asp-items="sel2"onchange="Somefunc()"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="input3" />
        
            <select asp-items="sel3"onchange="Somefunc()"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    window.onload = function () { Somefunc() }

    function Somefunc() {
        $('#table tr').each(function () {
            $(this).children('td').each(function () {
                var selectvalue = $(this).children('select').val().toString()
                $(this).children('input').val(selectvalue)
                
            });
        });
    }
    
    
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

**Update**:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () { Somefunc() }

    function Somefunc() {
        $('select').each(function () {
            var selectvalue = $(this).prev('input').val().toString()
            console.log(selectvalue)
            if (selectvalue != null) {               
                $(this).children("option").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() == selectvalue) {
                        $(this).attr("selected", "selected")
                        $(this).val(selectvalue)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } 
    
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: No, that doesn't sound like my question

Comment: " I want to display their selected value in the editing form" isn't it what you want ？ could you explain more clearly？

Comment: When I go to the edit form, the list of several people is displayed with the registered values, but their values are not displayed in the dropdown.

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it